# Ошибка sqlite3 table sqlitedb_developers already exists

Tags: python, sqlite3

Есть код:

```
import sqlite3

try:
    sqlite_connection = sqlite3.connect('sqlite_python.db')
    sqlite_create_table_query = '''CREATE TABLE sqlitedb_developers (
                                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
                                name TEXT NOT NULL,
                                email text NOT NULL UNIQUE,
                                joining_date datetime,
                                salary REAL NOT NULL);'''

    cursor = sqlite_connection.cursor()
    print("База данных подключена к SQLite")
    cursor.execute(sqlite_create_table_query)
    sqlite_connection.commit()
    print("Таблица SQLite создана")

    cursor.close()

except sqlite3.Error as error:
    print("Ошибка при подключении к sqlite", error)
finally:
    if (sqlite_connection):
        sqlite_connection.close()
        print("Соединение с SQLite закрыто")
```

Ввиду того, что я новичок в sqlite, я не понимаю, что было сделано не так. Помогите мне разобраться в этом. Может я что-то не то скачал?

P.S. код с сайта https://pythonru.com/biblioteki/vvedenie-v-sqlite-python. Учусь по нему.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS sqlitedb_developers`

Comment: Ну наверное вы уже запускали этот скрипт и таблица уже была создана. Второй раз ту же таблицу нельзя уже создать.

Answer (score 0):

> *В sqlite нет типа datetime вместо него используется тип text.
> Соответственно нет и инструментов для работы с подобными данными.
> В связи с этим (на будущее) рекомендую использовать
> либо данные даты времени записанные в формат 
>
> ISO `YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS` (`datetime.isoformat()` в python) в виде типа text для sqlite 
>
> либо timestamp (`datetime.timestamp()` в python) в виде real для sqlite*
> [Ссылка на инфо](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)

```py
import sqlite3

# здесь не может возникнуть ошибки, 
# поскольку если этого файла нет, 
# обработчик его создаст

conn = sqlite3.connect('sqlite_python.db')
sqlite_create_table_query = """
    CREATE TABLE
    -- добавление `if not exists` исключает 
    -- попытку создания таблицы если она уже существует
    -- соответственно делая не нужным весь блок `try`
    if not exists

    developers (
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        email text NOT NULL UNIQUE,

        -- вот про это место я писал выше,
        -- у Вас здесь тип datetime
        joining_date text,
        salary REAL NOT NULL
    );
"""

conn.execute(
    sqlite_create_table_query
)
conn.close()
```